# when database is in simple recovery mode, can it have log wait?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have heard that when the database is in simple mode it cannot have a log wait.
but if you see on the attached picture this is exactly the case.
is there anything I can do to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: 'Simple' recovery just means it automatically 'cleans up' the log without you needing to back it up. It still definitely uses the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a database in simple recovery can have a log reuse wait as you can see.  You cannot avoid this.  For example, if you start a transaction and never commit, the log will eventually fill since the checkpoint can't reuse a virtual log containing an active transaction.  This is a side effect that the log is used to guarantee transaction durability.